# How to serialize instances of classes generated by DbMetal?

Tags: datacontractserializer, dblinq, iserializable, dbmetal

I noticed DbMetal generates classes that don't implement the `ISerializable` interface, nor are marked with `DataContractAttribute`. What is the easiest way of serializing such classes? Is there any DbMetal parameter that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class YourClassName { }
```

See [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for further details